# Not able to debug a Javascript challenge

Tags: javascript

I currently doing a challenge that requires me to debug a code snippet. The challenge states that there are bugs in the code that need to be changed so it can log true, true, true instead of true, false, false like it's currently doing.

The code snippet is:

```
import BigNumber from 'bignumber.js';

const denominationsMultiplier = {
  WEI: new BigNumber(1, 10).times(10).exponentiatedBy(18),
  GWEI: new BigNumber(1, 10).times(10).exponentiatedBy(8),
  ETH: new BigNumber(1, 10).times(10).exponentiatedBy(1),
}

function getFiatValueToRender({
  value,
  conversionRate = 1,
  fromDenomination,
  fromCurrency,
}) {
  let number = new BigNumber(value, 16);
  if (fromCurrency !== 'ETH') {
    number = number.multipliedBy(conversionRate);
  }
  if (fromDenomination !== 'WEI') {
    number = number.multipliedBy(
      denominationsMultiplier.WEI
        .dividedBy(denominationsMultiplier[fromDenomination])
    )
  }
  return number.toString(32);
}

function getResult(value) {
  return getFiatValueToRender({
    value,
    conversionRate: 1,
    fromDenomination: 'GWEI',
    fromCurrency: 'ABC',
  })
}

let x = 0

console.log(getResult(0) === '0')
console.log(getResult(1) === '59682f00')
console.log(getResult(10600.47) === 'e762bdf8a40')
```

The challenge says the the bugs are specifically on lines 5, 15, 25, and 31 and by changing decimal numbers on those lines, the code can be fixed and make it log true, true, true. I'm really struggling on grasping what the issue is. I know that the function takes a value, its denomination, currency, and a conversion rate as input, performs calculations based on these parameters, and returns the value converted to a base-32 string. However, I'm not seeing how I can debug the `console.log(getResult(1) === '59682f00')` test to have it pass? Can I get help with outlining the steps needed to debug the test to successfully figure out what changes are needed to fix the "bugs" in this challenge?

Comment: What `fromDenomination` does the function handle? What value is being passed in the argument?

Comment: @Barmar `getFiatValueToRender` is handling any `fromDenomination` that is not `WEI`. In the code we are just handling the `GWEI` denomination.

Comment: `59682f00` base 16 = `1500000000` base 10 if that helps.  and `0` and `1` are unambiguously 0 and 1 respectively in any/every base system.  Also, 1 GWEI is 1e9 WEI

Comment: And you can convert base 32 to base 10 yourself using [unitconverters.net](https://www.unitconverters.net/numbers/base-32-to-decimal.htm)

Comment: @Wyck Ok I had actually used that website but since using `59682f00` as base32 to convert to decimal returns `181672164352`, this result wasn't looking like something the code can use to convert the value given in `getResult`. Looking at the conversion from base 16 to base 10 now is making more sense. So would that mean that in the code `GWEI: new BigNumber(1, 10).times(10).exponentiatedBy(8),` needs to be `exponentiatedBy(9)`?

Comment: @feners, It would seem that yes, the output is being expressed in base 16, and that the conversion rate is 1.5 base 10 (not 1.0) (from test case #2) and that the input is expressed in base 10, not base 16 because `e762bdf8a40` base 16 is 15900705000000, (which is 10600.47 * 1.5 * 1e9) (from test case #3)

Comment: @Wyck I am somewhat following, mind explaining a bit more? :)

Comment: @Wyck That means `let number = new BigNumber(value, 16);` should be `BigNumber(value, 10);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your three assertions can be made true by making the following changes to the code:

- 1 WEI is 1e9 GWEI (not 1e8).  Change the exponent from `8` to `9`.
  `GWEI: new BigNumber(1, 10).times(10).exponentiatedBy(9),`
- The input is being expressed in base 10, not base 16.  Change the base from `16` to `10`.
  `let number = new BigNumber(value, 10);`
- The output is being expressed in base 16, not base 32.  Change the output base from `32` to `16`.
  `return number.toString(16);`
- The conversion rate is actually 1.5, not 1.0.  Change the conversion rate from `1` to `1.5`.
  `conversionRate: 1.5`

Some clues that help in reverse engineering a solution:

- `59682f00` base 16 is `1500000000` base 10.
- `0` and `1` are unambiguously 0 and 1 respectively in any/every base system.  This makes test 2 explicitly define the product of the conversion rate and GWEI to WEI.  We can logically assume that GWEI is 1e9 WEI.  (It helps to have some familiarity with Ethereum to recognize the WEI unit of cryptocurrency and that G is the "giga-" prefix of the metric system.)
- `e762bdf8a40` base 16 is `15900705000000` base 10.  Divided by the GWEI scale gives 15900.705, and dividing by the conversion rate of 1.5 gives the original 10600.47 meaning the input was in base 10.

```js
const denominationsMultiplier = {
  WEI: new BigNumber(1, 10).times(10).exponentiatedBy(18),
  GWEI: new BigNumber(1, 10).times(10).exponentiatedBy(9),
  ETH: new BigNumber(1, 10).times(10).exponentiatedBy(1),
}

function getFiatValueToRender({
  value,
  conversionRate = 1,
  fromDenomination,
  fromCurrency,
}) {
  let number = new BigNumber(value, 10);
  if (fromCurrency !== 'ETH') {
    number = number.multipliedBy(conversionRate);
  }
  if (fromDenomination !== 'WEI') {
    number = number.multipliedBy(
      denominationsMultiplier.WEI
        .dividedBy(denominationsMultiplier[fromDenomination])
    )
  }
  return number.toString(16);
}

function getResult(value) {
  return getFiatValueToRender({
    value,
    conversionRate: 1.5,
    fromDenomination: 'GWEI',
    fromCurrency: 'ABC',
  })
}

console.log(getResult(0) === '0')
console.log(getResult(1) === '59682f00')
console.log(getResult(10600.47) === 'e762bdf8a40')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bignumber.js/8.0.2/bignumber.min.js"></script>
```